# ANTLR: Why the invalid input could match the grammar definition

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I've written a very simple grammar definition for a calculation expression:

```
grammar SimpleCalc;

options {
    output=AST;
}

tokens {
    PLUS  = '+' ;
    MINUS = '-' ;
    MULT = '*' ;
    DIV = '/' ;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ID  : ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0' .. '9')+ ;

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { Skip(); } ;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

start: expr EOF;

expr : multExpr ((PLUS | MINUS)^ multExpr)*;

multExpr : atom ((MULT | DIV)^ atom )*;

atom : ID
     | '(' expr ')' -> expr;
```

I've tried the invalid expression `ABC &* DEF` by `start` but it passed. It looks like the `&` charactor is ignored. What's the problem here?

Comment: How did you checked this grammar? Have you tried parsing expressions with this grammar in AntlrWorks?

Comment: I tried the generated code and it gets the result `ABC * DEF` for `ABC &* DEF`.

Comment: Mmm... please, provide us the code, which you use for invoking *start* rule and for determination output AST structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your invalid expression `ABC &= DEF` hasn't been passed; it causes `NoViableAltException`.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I've made a mistake in the question. The invalid expression is `ABC &* DEF`. It's `*` instead of `=`.

Comment: @JeffreyZhao Check out some of the questions and answers regarding ANTLR error handling, for example [this one that I answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889941/how-to-stop-antlr-from-suppressing-syntax-errors) about "disappearing" syntax errors. My guess is that ANTLR is detecting the error, writing to `System.err`, and removing the bad input,  but none of the details are reaching you/the user.

Comment: @JeffreyZhao, this doesn't matter, the same result as I mentioned above is for "ABC &* DEF". Your grammar is unable to parse expressions with "&" symbol. Have you tried test this grammar in ANTLRWorks?